# Referencing another collection Mongoose (MONGO)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If i have two Schema's as follows;

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  telegramId: Number,
  username: String,
  balance: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  totalTopUp: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  totalRefunds: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  totalOrders: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  joined: Date,
});

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  orderId: String,
  cardId: String,
  userId: Number,
  refunded: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  baseId: String,
  price: Number,
  date: Date,
});
```

Where telegramId in userSchema and userId in orderSchema will match when a user makes an order, is it possible to have totalOrders in userSchema automatically update via some sort of referencing. Or will updates to totalOrders need to be made via code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use post('save') middleware over orderSchema, on each new document you can increase the total orders.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-post